# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PasswordPolicies' in Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I was trying to set the password for an Azure user to not expire forever. In the process I tried below commands

```
Get-AzADUser -ObjectId <valid Azure user> | Select-Object UserprincipalName,@{
>>     N="PasswordNeverExpires";E={$_.PasswordPolicies -contains "DisablePasswordExpiration"}
>> }

UserPrincipalName          PasswordNeverExpires
-----------------          --------------------
<valid Azure user>                        False
```

To set PasswordNeverExpires to True, I executed below command

```
Set-AzADUser -ObjectId <valid Azure user> -PasswordPolicies DisablePasswordExpiration
```

But it throws an error as below:

```
Update-AzADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PasswordPolicies'.
At line:1 char:51
+ ... ADUser -ObjectId <valid Azure user> -PasswordPolicies Disable ...
+                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Update-AzADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.UpdateAzureADUserCommand
```

Can someone help me on this issue please.

Thanks,
Sri Ram.

Comment: Take a look at [Update-AzADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/update-azaduser?view=azps-4.6.1)'s documentation. There is no such a switch as `PasswordPolicies`, so where did you get an idea to use it?

Comment: I am not familier with AD or AzADUsers, but it seems that "PasswordPolicies" is not a valid parameter. Can you check if it is really a parameter or a method?

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Where did you find the `PasswordPolicies` property?

Comment: Hi do you have a chance to check my answer? Is there any update?

Answer (score 0):

Az Powershell doesn't provide the setting password policy feature.

Use [Azure AD Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy#set-a-password-to-never-expire) instead.

```
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId <user ID> -PasswordPolicies DisablePasswordExpiration
```

If you are concerned about having to log in to Azure AD Powershell again, you can [connect a session using an existing token associated with the active azure context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0#example-4--connect-a-session-using-an-existing-token-associated-with-the-active-azure-context).

For example:

```
# login
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant {your tenant}
# perform other Azure operations...

$currentAzureContext = Get-AzContext
$tenantId = $currentAzureContext.Tenant.Id
$accountId = $currentAzureContext.Account.Id
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenantId -AccountId $accountId
```

Then you can run `Set-AzureADUser` cmd.